# Lorentz group representation of spin 2 particles

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I am beginner in particle physics and I have the following understanding of Lorentz group. Correct me if I am wrong. We know that Lorentz algebra is characterised by the eigenvalues $m(m + 1)$ and $n(n+ 1)$ of the square of the operators
$$
\vec{N} = \frac{1}{2} (\vec{J} + i \vec{K}) \\
\vec{N^{\dagger}}= \frac{1}{2} (\vec{J} - i \vec{K}) ,
$$
where $\vec{J}$ is the generator of rotation and $\vec{K}$ the generator of boosts. Then the pair $(m,n)$ gives different representations of the Lorentz group.

My problem is:

[image]

I am reading the book of Pierre Ramond on field theory, Page 22. I don’t understand why $ (0,0) \oplus (1,1) $ is the symmetric part and $ (0,2) \oplus (2,0) $ (I think in the book it’s mistakenly written as $ (0,1) \oplus (1,0) $) is the antisymmetric part in the above equation 1.4.64? Here the symbols have usual meaning.

Comment: The second question should be asked as a seperate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$(a,b) \otimes (c,d) = (a \otimes c, b \otimes d) \tag{1}$$

so

$$(1/2,1/2) \otimes (1/2,1/2) = (1/2\otimes 1/2, 1/2\otimes 1/2)$$
$$ = (1 \oplus 0, 1/2\otimes 1/2)$$
$$ = (1, 1/2\otimes 1/2) \oplus (0, 1/2\otimes 1/2)$$
$$ = (1, 1 \oplus 0) \oplus (0, 1 \oplus 0)$$
$$ = (1, 1 ) \oplus (1, 0) \oplus (0, 1 )\oplus (0,0)$$
$$ = \left[ (0, 0) \oplus (1,1) \right]\oplus  \left[ (1,0) \oplus (0,1)\right]$$

It's correct and not a typo. Typically when using product representations (your example is Rarita-Schwinger without the Dirac part), you'll find a spin background that leads to extra degrees of freedom, unless you impose some conditions.

$(1/2,1/2)$ can be interpreted as the coupling of two spinors with each other $(1/2,0) \otimes (0,1/2) = (1/2,1/2)$. As thus you (might) already know that they can couple to a triplet and a spinor. In terms of dof this is $2 \otimes 2 = 3 \oplus 1$, in terms of spin this is $1/2 \otimes 1/2 = 1 \oplus 0$.

Your "raw" spin-2 field thus has the following spin contents:

$$(1 \oplus 0) \otimes (1 \oplus 0) = 1\otimes 1 \oplus 0 \otimes 1 \oplus 1 \otimes 0 \oplus 0\otimes 0$$
$$ = \underbrace{2 \oplus 1 \oplus 0}_{(1,1)} \oplus \underbrace{1 \oplus 1}_{(1,0)\oplus(0,1)} \oplus \underbrace{0}_{(0,0)}$$

So your $(1,1)$ tensor needs $5+3+1 = 9$ degrees of freedom.

It has two Lorentz indices $T_{\mu\nu}$ and thus 16 components in total. Making it symmetric means there are only $10$ independend components. Making it traceless fixes another component, thus the required $9$.

From this you can follow, that in order to have the needed $9$ dof, your tensor must be traceless and symmetric.

Your $(1,0) \oplus (0,1)$ tensor has $3+3=6$ degrees of freedom.
If you again start with a 2-index tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ with 16 entries, antisymmetry $T_{\mu\nu}= -T_{\nu\mu}$ eliminates the diagonal (-4 indices) and poses a condition on the remaining 12 (-6 indices) leaving you with a total of 6 independent entries. The electro-magnetic fieldstrength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ is an example for a $(1,0)\oplus(0,1)$ tensor.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. In a similar way can we say (1,0) tensor requires only 4 degrees of freedom?

Comment: @SagarKumarBiswal See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: One more quick question, what does a single (1,0) or (0,1) mean? For example in 1/2 case they represent left and right handed spinors.

Comment: By analogy that would be left and right handed vectors. I recommend Robinson's Symmetry and the Standard Model, chapter 3.3. There you can read in detail about how to figure out the transformation properties ob different representations. While he shows no example for (1,0) or (0,1), surely that would be a great exercise to confirm.

Comment: Okay. thank you.

Comment: @SagarKumarBiswal actually scratch that. It's clearly not a vector. There should still be some handedness involved, but not vectors. You should do the calculations and see for yourself, how those parts transform.

Comment: Yes. I know they are some kind of self dual and anti self dual 2nd rank tensors. But I was asking for their physical significance. But thanks for the book recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer, but

1. Just by counting dimensions, $(0,1)\oplus (1,0)$ is correct.  $(1/2,1/2)$ has dimension 4.  So $(1/2,1/2)\otimes (1/2,1/2)$ dimension 16.  In the decomposition, $(0,0)$ has dimension $1\times 1=1$, $(1,1)$ has dimension $3\times 3=9$, $(0,1)$ has dimension $1\times 3=3$ and $(1,0)$ has dimension $3\times 1=3$.  $1+9+3+3=16$ so it checks out.
2. About Weyl spinors, those are the $(1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/2)$ representations.  One is 'left-handed' and the other 'right-handed' (not sure which is which.)  The representations are on $\Bbb{C}^2$ given by the formulas
   $$\begin{split}
   A\circ_1 v = Av\\
   A\circ_2 v = \overline{A}v
   \end{split}$$
   where $v\in\Bbb{C}^2$, $A$ is either in $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb{C})$ or $SL(2,\Bbb{C})$ and $\overline{A}$ denotes complex conjugation of the matrix elements.
   Note that deciding which one is $(1/2,0)$ and which one is $(0,1/2)$ is basis-dependent and a matter of convention.  The map $A\mapsto \overline{A}$ is an outer automorphism of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb{C})$ as a real Lie algebra that flips the signs of $J_1,K_2,J_3$ and has the effect of swapping $(p,q)$ and $(q,p)$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.